# Installing FSPS raises error in spite of environment variable being set

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install the fsps library with pip. I am using Python 3.7.5 and pip 19.3.1 on Fedora 30. 
I have installed FSPS following the instructions [here](https://github.com/cconroy20/fsps/blob/master/doc/INSTALL), and numpy is installed. But when I run

```
pip3 install fsps
```

I get the following error

```
Collecting fsps
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3d/4f/3491667b60f9e202bf755c18e6e03048bd003c4b9b33dd832c446171d940/fsps-0.2.2.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-smda6ikh/fsps/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-smda6ikh/fsps/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-smda6ikh/fsps/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-smda6ikh/fsps/
    Complete output (16 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/pip-install-smda6ikh/fsps/fsps/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
        ev = os.environ["SPS_HOME"]
      File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
        raise KeyError(key) from None
    KeyError: 'SPS_HOME'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-smda6ikh/fsps/setup.py", line 87, in <module>
        from fsps import __version__  # NOQA
      File "/tmp/pip-install-smda6ikh/fsps/fsps/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
        raise ImportError("You need to have the SPS_HOME environment variable")
    ImportError: You need to have the SPS_HOME environment variable
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I did add `SPS_HOME=/path/to/fsps/` and `export SPS_HOME` to my `.bashrc`, and the compiled `.o` and `.mod` files are in `${SPS_HOME}/src`. `echo $SPS_HOME` does show the path.

---

I tried to install from [source](https://github.com/dfm/python-fsps). Running

```
git clone https://github.com/dfm/python-fsps.git
cd python-fsps
python setup.py install
```

raises the same kind of error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/python-fsps/fsps/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    ev = os.environ["SPS_HOME"]
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SPS_HOME'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 87, in <module>
    from fsps import __version__  # NOQA
  File "/home/user/python-fsps/fsps/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise ImportError("You need to have the SPS_HOME environment variable")
ImportError: You need to have the SPS_HOME environment variable
```

How can I solve this error and install FSPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did add `SPS_HOME=/path/to/fsps/` to my `.bashrc`

Environment variables should be added to `~/.bash_profile` (though `~/.bashrc` is also tolerable).

For environment variables to be visible in subprocesses you must export them. Add this after setting the variable:

```
export SPS_HOME
```

Comment: I put `SPS_HOME=...` in `.bash_profile` instead, and added `export SPS_HOME` to `.bash_profile`. I still get the same error

Comment: Did you restarted the shell? If not you can run `export SPS_HOME` right in the running shell.

Comment: I restarted the shell and even rebooted my computer. I am still getting `ImportError: You need to have the SPS_HOME environment variable` when I run `python setup.py install`. I also ran `export SPS_HOME` in the shell, to no avail.

Comment: `python -c 'import os; print(os.environ["SPS_HOME"])'` BTW do you really use bash? Could it be that `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc` are simply not used? `echo $SHELL`

Comment: The output of that is the content of `$SPS_HOME`. I am using bash. Even when I run `SPS_HOME=... export SPS_HOME` in the terminal before running `python setup.py install`, I still get the same error.

Comment: That's very strange. It seems `SPS_HOME` is cleared somewhere in `setup.py` or called modules.

Comment: I figured out the problem : when installing as root, it didn't access the environment variable I had set as non root.

Comment: So you've removed `sudo` before asking question? This makes answering rather hard, no? :-(

Comment: At first, I was getting the error with and without sudo. Sorry about that :/